# Mobile number validation which restricts 0 as first number

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc

I need to validate mobile number. since it should have 10 digit and it should only allow numbers. My requirement is the first digit shouldnt be 0

```
public string mobile{set; get;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is a property on your model, use a [RegularExpressionAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.regularexpressionattribute(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
[RegularExpression("^[1-9]\d{9}$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid phone number")]
public string mobile { set; get; }
```

Comment: Why `[2-9]`? i think it would be `[1-9]`.